# Casting memory to union

Tags: c++, casting, bit-fields, memory-layout

I would like to allocate some memory, initialize it to some values and then cast different segments of this memory to different structures. Something as follows:

```
union structA{
  __int8 mem[3];

  struct{
    unsigned field1 : 8;
    unsigned field2 : 12; 
    unsigned field3 : 4;
  };
};

struct structB{
  __int8 mem[10];
};


__int8 globalMem[128];

structA a1 <---- &globalMem[0]
structA a2 <---- &globalMem[10]
structB b1 <---- &globalMem[30]
```

I tried using reinterpret_cast and I don't get any compiler error but it seems that my variables (`a1`, `a2` and `b1`) are not really assigned/initialized correctly.

Any idea about why this is not working and what is the correct way to achieve something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Bitfield alignment and padding is implementation defined. You will need to investigate whether or not your compiler added padding to your structure with the bitfields. Highly likely.

Comment: Also using a signed underlying type (`__int8 `) might not be the best idea.

Comment: try to wrap your program with 
`pragma pack(push,1)
  PROGRAM
pragma pack(pop)`
It should eliminate any padding problems as Sam Varshavchik mentioned.

Comment: What is __int8? This is not something which C++ defines.

Comment: I was trying to use __int8 (or any other type) to have consistency between my definitions and also to overcome the alignment problem between my globalMem and instantiated objects of structA and structB

Comment: Is placement new operator the keyword you are looking for? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/222557/6695750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you intend to do requires the use of a `reinterpret_cast`:

```
structA a1 = *reinterpret_cast<structA*>(&globalMem[0]);
structA a2 = *reinterpret_cast<structA*>(&globalMem[10]);
structB b1 = *reinterpret_cast<structB*>(&globalMem[30]);
```

**What's wrong with this ?**

This requires extreme care, because a C++ `struct` is a special kind of `class`, and this kind of assignment does not respect the object semantic (because the content at the different `globalMem` addresses is not initialized as proper object unless you'd use [placement new](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new) somewhere in your code).

You could also make sure that `structA` is trivially copyable (`is_trivially_copyable<structA>::value` which fortunately is true here) before using this kind of tricks.

In addition, there could be an issue with alignment constraints which might not be respected, as `globalMem` has no alignment constraint, but depending on compiler/architecture, `structA` could require a word alignment.

Finally, the size of `structA` is not necessarily 3 as you tend to think. In fact on some compilers it will be 4, as in **[this online demo](http://ideone.com/K3PYpT)**

**Additional remarks**

You could use standard types `uint8_t` instead of compiler specific type name starting with double underscore.

Regarding alignment and size topic, I'd advise you to be very prudent about memory layout assumptions. I'd rather suggest for your `globalMem` to consider making it a struct of all the structures it contains, so to ensure proper object semantic and have a safe layout.

Comment: but this only copies part of globalMem to a1, etc. It really doesn't "map" a1, a2 and b1 to parts of globalMem.

Comment: @Ali there are a couple of issues on you layout (see edit), which makes me think that your mapping control takes wrong assumptions (starting with the size of struct A).  I invite you to look at this online demo: http://ideone.com/K3PYpT where you'll see that a prpeprly initialized object is properly copied despite the reinterpret cast.  However, reinterpret cast usually spots a tricky design that's worth reconsidering.